# Python using Pandas to_sql: How do I add the data from Excel to MariaDB without writing the data to the ID and timestamp column?

Tags: python, mysql, excel, pandas, mariadb

I want to import data from Excel into a database using Pandas.

In my database that I created using MariaDB, I have in the first column the ID that automatically increments and in the second column a timestamp.
The data I have in Excel I want to insert from the third column in the MariaDB.
In addition, the data in Excel does not have a heading.

I have already written something but it does not work. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

This is my Code what I'm using to insert an Excel-File into my MariaDB Database:

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

df = pd.read_excel(r'C:/Users/Zlatan/Desktop/Project_PolymerSQL/guitest.xlsx', header=None, index_col=0)

# format: mysql://user:pass@host/db
engine = create_engine("mariadb+mariadbconnector://root:pass@127.0.0.1:3306/polymer")
df.to_sql('guitest', con=engine, if_exists='append', index=False)
```

This is an example of data in Excel (without heading). The data starts at column A and row 1:

```
test11  test21  1
test11  test21  2
test11  test21  3
test11  test21  4
test11  test21  5
test11  test21  6
test11  test21  7
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by assigning column names when you read the Excel file, and then dropping the columns that you don't need before writing to the database. The column name(s) that you want to write to the database must match those in the database table.

Given this table

```
+-------+-----------+------+-----+---------------------+-------------------------------+
| Field | Type      | Null | Key | Default             | Extra                         |
+-------+-----------+------+-----+---------------------+-------------------------------+
| id    | int(11)   | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment                |
| ts    | timestamp | NO   |     | current_timestamp() | on update current_timestamp() |
| col_c | int(11)   | YES  |     | NULL                |                               |
+-------+-----------+------+-----+---------------------+-------------------------------+
```

This code

```py
df = pd.read_excel('guitest.xlsx', header=None, index_col=0, names=['col_b', 'col_c'])

new_df = df.drop(df.columns[[0]], axis=1)

new_df.to_sql('guitest', con=engine, if_exists='append', index=False)
```

will insert these rows

```
+----+---------------------+-------+
| id | ts                  | col_c |
+----+---------------------+-------+
|  1 | 2021-09-25 07:21:08 |     1 |
|  2 | 2021-09-25 07:21:08 |     2 |
|  3 | 2021-09-25 07:21:08 |     3 |
|  4 | 2021-09-25 07:21:08 |     4 |
|  5 | 2021-09-25 07:21:08 |     5 |
|  6 | 2021-09-25 07:21:08 |     6 |
|  7 | 2021-09-25 07:21:08 |     7 |
+----+---------------------+-------+
```

Comment: Thanks, but the solution expects a heading in Excel.
The data in my Excel file does not have a heading. They start directly at row 1 and column A

Comment: The solution does not require headers in Excel, only that you assign headers when you read the Excel file.

Comment: Okay thanks that worked. Had to delete the parameter "index_col=0" because the first column (column A) was not copied.

Can you tell me why the ID does not increase +1 but +14 as soon as I write new data into the MariaDB?

`"ID"         "Timestamp"   "Test1text"    "Test2varchar" "Test3int"\r
"176" "2021-10-07 07:07:50" \N               "test21"         "18"\r
"190" "2021-10-07 07:08:30" "test11"       "test21"         "1"`

Comment: No idea I'm afraid; if you're referring to the id in the db table, and it's set to auto increment then it might be a setting in the database; if auto increment is off then it must be coming from Pandas.